# mysqli - How to fetch a row without modifying the result set?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to extract a value from `mysqli_result` without fetching a row i.e. without modifying the result set as I need it in full later in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also point the iterator back to the beginning. ie..

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    //do stuff with the result
}
//back to the start
mysqli_data_seek($result,0);
```

now the pointer is returned to the beginning. [mysqli_data_seek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all and store in an array…

```
$results = [];
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM WHATEVER");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    array_push($results, $row);
}
//Now $results is fully populated
```

Comment: You can replace the loop with `$results = $sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);`